# Has jQuery taken a backwards approach to method chaining?

Tags: jquery, method-chaining

Is it just me who find the following code intrinsically backwards?

I am using [this posting](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain) as a reference.

```
// create the inner div
var $inner = $("<div>inner</div>")

   // append it to a new outer div
   .appendTo("<div>outer</div>")

   // next change the jQuery chain to the "outer" div 
   .parent()

      // append the outer div to the body
      .appendTo("body")

   // finally, go back to the last destructive command, 
   // giving us back a pointer to the "inner" div
   .end();
```

My initial approach would have been to grab the **body**, then append an **outer** to the body, and then append an **inner** to the outer.

Approaching it backwards and then jumping around the hierarchy with things like `parent ()` just strikes me as a little curious...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it the other way too:

```
$('body').append('<div>outer</div>').append('<div>inner<div>');
```

but that will leave you at `body`

To end up at `inner` you'd need to:

```
$('body').append('<div>outer</div>').append('<div>inner<div>')
.find('div:contains(inner)');
```

Comment: jQuery 1.3 changed a bunch of things, so I think the second paragraph may be redundant in that you will automatically end up at div:inner without needing to find.

Answer (score 2):

The thing with jQuery is, you can do what you like with it. If that particular style doesn't suit you, you don't have to use it.

I find method chaining helps in a lot of cases, but in the particular case you bring up I would do something different - I agree that it's not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

not really, it all depends what you wish to chain afterwards, using appendTo gives you access to the new element rather than the element you appended to.